# Balls and colors

Tags: probability

Somebody puts eight balls into a bowl. The balls have been colored independently of each other and each ball has been colored red or white with equal probabilities. This all happens unseen to you. Then you see that two red balls are added to bowl. Next five balls ball are taken at random from the bowl and are shown to you. All these five balls are white. What is the probability that all the other five balls in the bowl are red?

That's my approach (apparently wrong).

Let $A=[$first five balls W$]$
$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B_1)\mathbb{P}(B_2|B_1)...\mathbb{P}(B_5|B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5)=\frac{x-k+1}{10-k+1}, k=1,...,5$ and $x\geq 5$.

Let $B=[$remaining five balls R$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(B|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B\cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{\frac{10-x-k+1}{5-k+1}}{\frac{x-k+1}{10-k+1}}$

where $\mathbb{P}(B\cap A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(R_6)\mathbb{P}(R_7|R_6)...\mathbb{P}(R_{10}|R_6,R_7R_8R_9,A)\mathbb{P}(A|R_6,R_7,R_8,R_9,R_{10})}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{10-x-k+1}{5-k+1},k=1,...,5$.

I say apparently because the text doesn't specify if the draw is "five balls one by one" or "all together". If I have to use $\operatorname{IpGeo}$, how do I set the problem? I know that with $8$ balls we can have $(5B,3R), (6B,2R), (7B,1R), (8B,0R),$ that becomes $(5B,3R+2R), (6B,2R+2R), (7B,1R+2R), (8B,0R+2R)$ with the addition of two red balls.

Anyway the solution is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the five balls which have been extracted from the bowl are white.  Moreover, you know that two of the remaining five balls must be red.  That leaves three balls, each with probability $1/2$ of being red.  Therefore, the probability that they are all red is $(1/2)^3 = 1/8$.

Comment: Please see my answer; I don't believe in coincidences.  Therefore, there must be something inherent in the problem that renders your reasoning valid.  I'm just not seeing it.  If you have an explanation why your reasoning is valid in such a *conditional probability setting*, please add an addendum to your answer.

Comment: @user2661923 why do you think conditional probability applies here? If I get $5$ heads in a row, does it improve the chances of a tail in $6th$ toss of a fair coin?

Comment: you can simply look at the 2nd problem independently - which is that there are $5$ balls in the bowl. You know $2$ are red and rest $3$ are randomly white or red. What is the probability of all $5$ being red? Keeping 2 reds aside, that have been added and that we already know about, let's talk of the rest $8$. Getting $5$ white has not changed the probability of rest $3$ being white or red.

Comment: +1 for your accurate analysis and answer

Comment: @MathLover I just **comprehended your comment.**  It makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the experience to be able to validate N.F. Taussig's analysis.  Therefore, I computed the problem via conditional probability baby steps, and got the identical answer.

Initially, when the bowl has exactly 8 balls in it, I would compute the
probability that the the bowl contains exactly $w$ white balls
(where $w \,\in \,\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$) as

$P_1(w) = \frac{\binom{8}{w}}{2^8}.$

After two red balls are added, let $P_2(w)$ denote the probability (as a function
of $w$) that the first 5 balls drawn are white.

If $0 \leq w \leq 4,$ then $P_2(w) = 0.$

If $5 \leq w \leq 8,$ then $P_2(w) = \frac{\binom{w}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}.$

Let $Q \equiv \sum_{w=0}^8 [P_1(w) \times P_2(w)].$

As I see it, the desired probability is $\frac{P_1(5) \times P_2(5)}{Q},$ which does compute as $\frac{1}{8}.$

**Addendum:**
Response to Math Lover's comments

"why do you think conditional probability applies here?..."

Because I see nothing invalid in my analysis to the original problem.

**However,** following N.F. Taussig's answer, Math Lover added an additional comment that **finally sunk in to my head.**

It's not that the conditional probability approach is invalid.  Instead, as Math Lover indicated, I can separate the first 5 balls drawn from the
remaining 5 (at least two of which must be red).  The distribution of whites and reds in the remaining 5 **must be** independent of the distribution of whites and reds in the first 5 balls drawn.

**There is a subtlety** that I feels is worth exploring.

Suppose that two alternative problems Q1 and Q2 were posed.

Q1:
The two red balls that were added have been labeled $R_1$ and $R_2$.
Of the first 5 balls drawn, you are given the following two facts.
a. Neither $R_1$ nor $R_2$ are among the first 5 drawn.
b. Exactly 3 of the first 5 drawn are white.

What is the chance that the remaining 5 balls are all red.

Q2:
The two red balls that were added have been labeled $R_1$ and $R_2$.
Of the first 5 balls drawn, you are given the following **single**  fact.
a. Exactly 3 of the first 5 drawn are white.

What is the chance that the remaining 5 balls are all red.

I would argue that N.F. Taussig's analysis also applies to Q1, but does not apply to Q2, because in Q2, you don't know which of $R_1$ and $R_2$ (if any) remain with the undrawn balls.

I would further argue that in the original problem, N.F. Taussig's analysis is valid, because since the first 5 drawn were all white, $R_1$ and $R_2$ could not have been among them.