# Bag of white and black balls, but adding two random balls first

Tags: probability

I've come across this exercise and I don't know where to start.

"In a bag there are 13 white balls and 4 black balls, and two balls are ADDED at random. I draw one ball and it's white, what are the chances that the next ball I draw is white too?" No replacement.

I know how to solve these exercises, but I don't know where to put the two random balls.

I hope you can give me a hand because I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Two balls are added or two balls are drawn? Replacement or without replacement?

Comment: @Remy two balls added. No replacement.

Comment: Without information of what types of balls are added, this can't be determined.

Comment: @Remy I thought so, but if we have been examined for something like this I suppose it is because it can be done.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819655/balls-and-colors/, especially the contrast between N.F. Taussig's answer and my (user 2661923) answer.  It can well be argued that (similar to the cited problem), your query broaches some subtleties that will challenge your mind.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera The colors of the two balls added are black and/or white?

Comment: @MathLover Thats the thing, we don't know the color of these two balls.

Comment: I think that it is reasonable to assume, that before any balls are drawn, the chances are (1/4) that 2 black balls are added, (1/4) that 2 white balls are added, and (1/2) that 1 black ball and 1 white ball are added.  I think that that is the only reasonable interpretation of the phrase **at random.**

Comment: The question should have mentioned that. You can take a case where they are both black/white and a case that they are outside these two colors. The second case is easy to work. The first case  (BB,WW,BW,WB)  needs to be solved using conditional probability.

Comment: I agree with Math Lover.  That is, although this problem might well yield to sophisticated analysis that avoids conditional probability, I strongly suspect that conditional probability is the *intended* approach.  Again, see the mathSE link re my first comment to this query.

Comment: By the way, it would be something of a breach of mathSE protocol to simply hand you a solution without your first showing that you have worked on the problem.  Please spend 30 minutes to an hour trying to solve the problem, and please show your work.